# SPSS Ranking Data In One Column

Tags: ranking, spss

I'm still new with SPSS, I Have Data For The Following :

Cereals    Vegetables  Fruit   Meat    Dairy   Fat Sugar   Pulses

I Have Also Computed The Variables With This Formula :

```
Total FCS = (Cereals*2)+(Vegetables)+(Fruits)+(Meat*4)+(Dairy*4)+(Sugar*0.5)+(Pulses*3)
```

Now I Want To Rank The Data from the Total FCS In One Column In Order To Make Graph From It As Following:

Rank as :

```
<28 Poor

>28.5 - <42     Borderline

>42.5   Acceptable
```

What Should I Do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `DO IF` statement to assign the ranks. Example below.

```
DO IF FCS < 28.
  COMPUTE RankFCS = 1.
ELSE IF FCS <= 42.5.
  COMPUTE RankFCS = 2.
ELSE.
  COMPUTE RankFCS = 3.
END IF.
VALUE LABELS RankFCS
1 'Poor'
2 'Borderline'
3 'Acceptable'.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a command called `Recode` in SPSS, you can use that command to create this rank variable. Recode command has two options 
1). `Recode into same variables` 
2). `Recode into Different variables`. 
I am using 2nd option as you need to create a new Rank variable.

```
 STRING RankFCS (A8).
 RECODE FCS (Lowest thru 28='Poor') (28.5 thru 42='Borderline')
 (42.5 thru      Highest='Acceptable') 
 INTO RankFCS.
 EXECUTE.
```